# VBA get amount of Time a key is pressed

Tags: vba, excel, keyevent

I want to do a Makro with VBA which measures the amount of time the user presses a key, for example Space. 
And when the user stops pressing it, the Time is stored and added to the time when the key is pressed again.

Im new to VBA and have some problems with the syntax. So I found the keyUP and keyDown functions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445497(v=vs.60).aspx), but it seems that im using it the wrong way.

My code so far:

```
Sub KeyTime()
Time_old = 0
Range("A1").Value = Time_old
If Form_KeyDown(vbKeySpace, 0) Then
    Start_time = Timer
    If Form_KeyUp(vbKeySpace, 0) Then
        End_time = Timer
        Time = End_time - Start_time + Time_old
        Time_old = Time
        Range("A1").Value = Time_old
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but you are trying to use this as an event of the form, right?

Comment: It should happen if the user presses the space key somewhere in the excel document.

Comment: Right, the code you posted was a bit misleading then as the form_KeyDown is an event triggered in forms, not in worksheets. Hence the solution presented by Thomas Inzina (a nice one!) will not work.

Comment: ok thanks, so what would be the solution for my problem like

Comment: You'll need to hook the keyboard [Capturing keypress in Excel Worksheet with VBA](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27118905/Capturing-keypress-in-Excel-Worksheet-with-VBA.html#answer36037939).  You could also create a keylogger that will log the keys no matter where they are pressed [http://fracta.net/fracta/index.php/forum/2-excel-vba-forum/20-simple-excel-vba-key-logger-macro](http://fracta.net/fracta/index.php/forum/2-excel-vba-forum/20-simple-excel-vba-key-logger-macro)

Answer (score 2):

The Userform's Key Events will not fire if a control has focus.  You'll need either use a global variable or a Static method to track the key press.

Here I use a Static array variable inside a sub routine the track all the standard key presses.

[image]

```
Sub CountKeyPresses(KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Static KeyCounts(255) As Long
    If KeyAscii <= 255 Then
        KeyCounts(KeyAscii) = KeyCounts(KeyAscii) + 1
        Me.Caption = "Key(" & Chr(KeyAscii) & ") was pressed " & KeyCounts(KeyAscii) & " times"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    CountKeyPresses KeyAscii
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    CountKeyPresses KeyAscii
End Sub
```

Comment: Benny seems to be looking for a key presses in spreadsheets not forms.